# Introduce country fixed effects to glm() and set "reference country"

Tags: r, glm

I need to introduce fixed effects (in this case: country dummies) into an otherwise simple `glm()` in R.

The country fixed effects variables in my data look like this:

```
country   country_a   country_b   country_c   y   x   ...
1         1           0           0
1         1           0           0
2         0           1           1
2         0           1           1
```

Would this be the correct way of *technically* implementing it? See below...
`glm(y ~ x + country_a + country_b + country_c, family=binomial(link="logit"))`

And if so, how would I set a specific country as reference category? I know that I need to drop one country because of the fact that I would have perfect collinearity if I didn't. And normally this would then be my reference country. But what if other countries "go NA" as well simply due to the fact that they only appear a few times in the data and therefore disappear from the analysis (listwise deletion)? Will `country_a` still be my reference category if I decide to drop it?

Or do I have to use the `Country` variable (left column) in the first place and would have to tell `glm()` somehow that this is a factor with no order? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: just use `country`, wrapped in `as.factor(country)`.

Comment: Would'd `as.factor(country)` still imply that there is an implicit order? And what about a "character" variable? Would this make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data like:

```
> d
  country         y         x
1       1 0.9610213 0.2586365
2       1 0.8561303 0.5972043
3       2 0.5463802 0.6412527
4       2 0.4703876 0.1126319
```

You can either convert to factor in the glm call:

```
> glm(y~factor(country),data=d)

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ factor(country), data = d)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)  factor(country)2  
          0.9086           -0.4002  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
Null Deviance:      0.1685 
Residual Deviance: 0.008388     AIC: -7.317
```

Or make a new column that makes it explicit its not numeric:

```
> d$CountryCode = paste0("Country",d$country)
> d
  country         y         x CountryCode
1       1 0.9610213 0.2586365    Country1
2       1 0.8561303 0.5972043    Country1
3       2 0.5463802 0.6412527    Country2
4       2 0.4703876 0.1126319    Country2
> glm(y~CountryCode,data=d)

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ CountryCode, data = d)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  CountryCodeCountry2  
             0.9086              -0.4002  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
Null Deviance:      0.1685 
Residual Deviance: 0.008388     AIC: -7.317
```

The missing factor level in the coefficient table is the baseline level - in this case `Country1`.

Comment: Thanks. The latter actually makese sense if I have the actual country names in the factor variable. But are you sure as.factor(country) would work? Wouldn't `glm()` assume there's still an order to it such as `1 < 2 < 3` like in "school education" where factor level `1` ("primary school") is smaller than `2` ("high school") is smaller than `3` ("university degree")?

Comment: So how would I tell `glm()` that there is a.) no order and b.) a reference catagory that is one specific country of my choice (let's say country no. 7 out of 23)?

Comment: If you convert to a factor then there is no ordering. You can call the levels "CountryA" to "CountryZ". To change the baseline I think you change the order of the levels in the factor - search for docs for glm in R...

Comment: Thanks. But if you allow me to ask: what about models that control for education and throw this variable in as "factor"? Wouldn't we lose the order that this var. has (such as the factor levels I mentioned above)? Would we I clue this as numeric? Or can I some how still throw this in as factor? I see it quite often that models feature different edu. levels and results (e.g. OR) on these separate levels.

Comment: If you have an "ordered factor", ie no degree < UG degree < PG degree but you don't want a linear effect then look at making a factor with "ordered=TRUE" and you'll get L (linear) Q (quadratic) and higher order terms. But this is way off your original question now.

Answer (score 1):

Since R's default (treatment) contrasts for categorical variables use the first factor level as the baseline/intercept, the easiest way to pick a baseline level is to use the `relevel()` function to make a specified level the first level (and move all the others down by one position).  Following @spacedman's answer, to do it on the fly:

```
glm(y~relevel(factor(country),"7"), data=d)
```

or:

```
d$CountryCode = relevel(factor(paste0("Country",d$country)), "Country7")
```